# .Net Core 2.2 Web API 405

Tags: c#, .net, webdav, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to setup a .net core 2.2 web api to use a post verb. Anything other than a get verb returns a 405 no matter if it is run on my local machine (w10 iis eXPRESS 10.0) or the windows server (2016 R2 IIS 8.0). I've read the other posts about disabling WebDav in your config file, adding a route, and completely removing the WebDav feature. I have done all of those to no avail. I'm just starting to develop in core and find this baffling, on the same server is a non-core web api that runs on .net framework 4.5 that processes GET,PUT,POST,DELETE without error. And yes, I have restarted the server after making changes to any of the configurations. The following are the web.config changes that I made, the last one coming directly from MS. Basic project that reproduces the same error on my machine and server is here https://github.com/FranciscanMedia/error405_core/tree/master it is just a standard web api project you get when you fire up VS2019.

```xml
<system.webServer>    
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
       <remove name="WebDAV" />
       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
       <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
          path="*."
          verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
          modules="IsapiModule"
          scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
          preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
          responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

```xml
<system.webServer>    
    <modules>        
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
    </modules>    
    <handlers>        
        <remove name="WebDAV" />    
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>    
</system.webServer>
```

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
           path="*."
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
           modules="IsapiModule"
           scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
           responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: What happens when you run with dotnet cli locally?

Comment: @joey Same thing happens, though the command line may give up more of the issue seems Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware is spitting the 405 back out. [Screen Grab] (https://pasteboard.co/IpbSUEd.jpg)

Comment: "may give up more of the issue" Not sure what that means. Try creating the issue in a public github repo with minimal code as described here. Your sure to get resolve after that https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ joey it simply means I did not receive a message other than 405 when using the browser and POSTMAN, the CLI gave me the namespace from which the error was produced (depicted in the screenshot) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Middleware . Still can't find anything about it yet. I fired up a core web api project and ran it on my machine/server with the same result. Can be found here :https://github.com/FranciscanMedia/error405_core/tree/master

Comment: Have you learned anything about this?  I am having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Why are you adding all of that to the config file, .Net Core supports this out of the box.  You haven't posted even remotely enough information for this to be a complete question.  1. You should post your controllers here and not a link. 2. You should post the Queries you've tried to hit. 3. It looks like @Vladimir Serykh answered your question already

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

It could be as simple as that. The reason is routing.

Just send your `POST` request to right URL like `https://localhost:44327/api/values/123`.

[image: POST request to correct and incorrect endpoints]

---

**Detailed explanation**

It's not the issue. It works as expected.

You make a `GET` request to `https://localhost:44327/api/values/`. It returns `200 OK`.

But when you make a `POST` request to the same URL `https://localhost:44327/api/values/`. It says `405 Method not allowed`.

However, you get `405`. It is happening because you are hitting the `GET` endpoint with `POST` method.

> Microsoft Docs says:
>
> ... the HTTP client sent a valid JSON request to the URL for a Web API application on a web server, but the server returned an HTTP 405 error message which indicates that the PUT method was not allowed for the URL. In contrast, if the request URI did not match a route for the Web API application, the server would return an HTTP 404 Not Found error.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

If you simply remove the `GET` endpoint. The `POST` request will start returning `404 Not found`. Which means that you are not hitting any registered route.

To send `POST` request you need to use different URL according to the routing rules.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost("{val}")]
    public StatusCodeResult Post()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This attribute-based configuration means that route of your `POST` endpoint is `/api/Values/{val}`. Where `{val}` is any value. It's not processed in the endpoint.

If you want to process it, you should pass it to the method:

```
[HttpPost("{val}")]
public StatusCodeResult Post(string val)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Didn't look fully at the code base but  is probably the answer

Comment: Your answer solved my problem.  My code differed a little from the OP's but when I commented out the GET actions, the 405 changed to 404 so it was a routing problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your controller you have to import another library.
Try

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

Instead of

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have defined:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

Then for the action:

```
[HttpPost("{val}")]
public StatusCodeResult Post()
{
        return Ok();
}
```

Your routing matches the following url:

https://localhost:44327/api/values/StatusCodeResult

It is going to take your main route defined on your controller [Route("api/[controller]")]

Then you are defining the "template" to use "{val}"

This is telling it to use the ActionResult **specific name** and to expect var val to be passed/appened.

Checking out the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

under section "Token replacement in route templates ([controller], [action], [area])"

They specifiy:

For convenience, attribute routes support token replacement by enclosing a token in square-braces ([, ]). The tokens [action], [area], and [controller] are replaced with the values of the action name, area name, and controller name from the action where the route is defined. In the following example, the actions match URL paths as described in the comments:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet] // Matches '/Products/List'
  public IActionResult List() {
    // ...
  }

  [HttpGet("{id}")] // Matches '/Products/Edit/{id}'
  public IActionResult Edit(int id) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If you want it to just route based on just verbs (follow a pattern where each api endpoint just handles operations for that specific object) then you would change your post method to just

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(string val)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Vladimir's answer. I dont have enough points to add comments to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57680022/11121833) by @vlaimir so i am adding my thoughts and suggestions.

The code you have on your github,

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost("{val}")]
public StatusCodeResult Post()
{
     return Ok();
}
```

This is a post and it would expect a value {val} per the route action configuration. Since you may try to hit the post without any value, thats not permitted. Ensure you supply some value and then do the POST. If you are using POSTMAN, you may have to supply the BODY of your request with some value. Swagger is a great util tool to embed into the web api's and that comes with excellent intuitive UI for our routes/resources. That might be even ideal to help determine and ensure you supply the right value.

Otherwise, you  dont need to modify or worry about your IIS or IIS Express settings. or webdav.